# The number of 4 digit numbers having their digits in non-decreasing order with digit $1,2,3$.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

### Question

> The number of 4 digit numbers having their digits in non-decreasing order (from left to right) constructed by using the digits belonging to the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ is _______.

#### My Solution/Approach

Taking help from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159210/non-decreasing-digits), I solved it as:

> Number of possible $4$ digits =

$$\sum_{l=0}^{3} \sum_{k=0}^{l} \sum_{j=0}^{k} \sum_{i=0}^{j}1
=\sum_{l=0}^{3} \sum_{k=0}^{l} \sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{j+1}{1}=\sum_{l=0}^{3} \sum_{k=0}^{l}  \binom{k+2}{2}$$

$$=\sum_{l=0}^{3} \binom{l+3}{3}=\binom{3+3}{3}=15$$

But I am not getting how 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{j}1=\binom{j+1}{1}$$

And also how 
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{j+1}{1}=\binom{k+2}{2}.$$

Please give me a hint to take over this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\sum_{i=0}^{j}1$ we sum the  number $1$ exactly $j+1$ times getting $j+1$ which is equal to $\binom{j+1}{1}$.
More generally, it follows from [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule) that   $$\sum_{j=0}^k\binom {j+d}{d}=\binom {k+d+1}{d+1}.$$

Actually your method is not correct. You are counting $4$ digit numbers having their digits in non-decreasing order (from left to right) constructed by using the digits belonging to the set {0,1,2,3}. Note that  $\sum_{l=0}^{3} \binom{l+3}{3}=\binom{3+4}{4}\not= \binom{3+3}{3}$.

Instead, the result can be achieved by counting the number of  non-negative integer solutions of the equation
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=4$$
where $x_i$ is the number of digits $i$ in the 4 digit number. By [Stars and bars method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159210/non-decreasing-digits), it is equal to
$$\binom{4+2}{2}=\frac{6\cdot 5}{2}=15.$$

Comment: for $\binom {k+2}{2}$, how is it derived ?

Comment: In general the sum $\sum_{j=0}^k\binom {j+d}{d}=\binom {k+d+1}{d+1}$.

Comment: what  is $d$ here?

Comment: It follows from Pascal's rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule
In your case the identity is used for $d=1,2,3$.

Comment: Actually your method is not correct because  $\sum_{l=0}^{3} \binom{l+3}{3}\not= \binom{3+3}{3}$.